# Posting image on friends wall using fb android sdk 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i m trying to post images on friends fb wall, im getting selected friend ID,
and image that is converted in base64 string
just getting response as error below

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 200, errorCode: 3, errorType: null, errorMessage: Unknown method}, isFromCache:false}
```

my code below

```
if (hasPublishPermission()) {

        Request postToWall = new Request();

        for (GraphUser friend : selectedFriends) {
            Constants.showLog("Selected Frnd", friend.getId());
            Constants.showLog("Selected Pic", picture);

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putByteArray("message", "Greetings from Wish Well!".getBytes());
            parameters.putByteArray("link", "http://pictwist.cloudganga.com".getBytes());
            parameters.putByteArray("picture", picture.getBytes());
            parameters.putByteArray("target_id", friend.getId().getBytes());

            postToWall = Request.newRestRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), friend.getId() + "/feed", parameters, HttpMethod.POST);


            Constants.showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Posted image on friend wall");


        }

        postToWall.setCallback( new Request.Callback() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) 
            {
                Constants.showLog("Responce Posting image", response.toString());

            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(postToWall);
    }
```

please help

Comment: you solved ur prblm? if yes then what was the prblm?

Comment: can you please share the code of `hasPublishPermission()`?

Answer (score 2):

Posting image or any content on friend's walls is no more supported by the sdk since feb 6, 2013. You need to use the feed dialog to do that..

check this link..

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/